# Facebook is telling me I need to submit my app for login review for permissions I never ask for

Tags: facebook

On my apps pages, facebook is showing me the following message:

> Your app is using permissions that require Login Review. You need to
>   submit and get approved for the following permissions before April 30,
>   2015 or your app will break: user_status, user_videos

But in my code, I never ask for those permissions (and my app has already been been approved for login review for the permissions I do ask for). Right now I'm thinking someone might be using our API keys for their own app. Is there a way to see a complete and detailed list of API calls that were made using my API key and does anyone know what's going to happen come April 30 since I can't/won't ask for login review for permissions I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're showing you these permissions,there can be 2 reasons for this happening:

1. You have some different versions of your app requesting these permissions which you don't know about. Please check the source code for that. It might also be possible that you were requesting these permissions while testing something.
2. If you've verified #1 above, it might be caused by token hijacking issue on your app. You should act on security your login by following the doc here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Once you've done both of these above, feel free to ignore this notice. This card is refreshed daily based on requests and it might fall off eventually. Also after April 30, 2015, these calls will fail anyway. So feel free to ignore it after you've verified the above 2 steps.

More information on why you see this card is on this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login/deadline#remindercard
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You were right, the notice eventually disappeared.